# UI Automation tree not visible on some machines

Tags: automated-tests, ui-automation, white-framework

I hava a set of tests that use White / UI Automation that run fine on my dev machine (Win 8.1 x64, .NET 4.5, NUnit, TD.NET and Console Runner). Another developer on Win 7, running the same suite, says that it fails when trying to get a UI element.

To investigate, I setup a win 2008 R2 machine, move the app and tests there and run them using the NUnit console runner and the tests are failing there as well.

I've tried:

- Dumpig the UI tree (LogStructure), the tree is clearly missing a lot of elements.
- Directly using automation API instead of white, exact same thing happens.
- Use Inspect and UIAVerify to inspect the tree, they DO show all the expected elements!
- Convert the app and test project to x86 and use x86 version of NUnit console runner, again tests fail with the same reason.

The failure is that, the test finds some of the elements (main window, some inner windows) and can get a reference to top level menu, but it can not find the AutomationElement in the subtree of the main menu (can not find a child element).

Any idea why this is happening on some of the machines?

Comment: What is the application written in that you are attempting to automate? Also is the main menu you are attempting to interact with a custom control? I ran into a problem like this when I was attempting to automate a tab control the company I work at developed. Basically the creation of the automationpeer was only happening when the control was hovered over because the mouse over event was fired. Try running inspect but only hover over the title bar for the application then dig down through the tree to your menu and see if all the elements are there.

Comment: @MaxYoung The issue turned out to be a OOTB behavior of DevExpress WPF suits. The decision was to turn off some stuff that'd affect automation frameworks for performance reasosns. There was a flag that'd turn those stuff back on (could be tied to a debug build or something) and doing that everything started working as expected. Read more about it in this [KB](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/KA18632)